# How to read the y value from the FieldName, FieldValue results map?

Tags: java, pmml

I have built an `org.jpmml.evaluator.Evaluator` from a PMML file

```
Evaluator evaluator = new LoadingModelEvaluatorBuilder()
    .load(new File(fileNamePmml))
    .build();
```

and evaluated it on a map of `FieldName, FieldValue`:

```
Map<FieldName, ?> results = evaluator.evaluate(arguments);
```

I can see the result is correct by printing the results:

```
{y={result=432.0}}
```

Now I want to read the value from the results:

```
double y = (double) results.get("y");
```

But I get the error

```
Error:(58, 48) java: incompatible types: capture#1 of ? cannot be converted to double
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with your code.

First, the keys of the `results` map are `org.dmg.pmml.FieldName`, not `java.lang.String`. You should be converting string keys to field name keys, otherwise all Map#get(Object) lookups will come back empty:

```
Map<FieldName, ?> results = evaluator.evaluate(..);
Object targetValue = results.get(FieldName.create("y"));
```

Second, map values are `java.lang.Object` subclasses. You're attempting to force-cast them to a Java primitive `double` value, which may or may not succeed, depending on the model. A much better idea would be to cast the value to `java.lang.Number`, and invoke its `Number#doubleValue()` method to obtain a primitive value. Yes, it's tedious and verbose, but it's safe:

```
Number targetValue = (Number)results.get(FieldName.create("y"));
double y = targetValue.doubleValue();
```

Comment: I get a `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jpmml.evaluator.mining.MiningModelEvaluator$1 cannot be cast to java.lang.Number`

Comment: Your model (random forest) is returning a so-called "complex result", which must be unpacked as detailed in JPMML-Evaluator project's README file: `Number targetValue = (Number)EvaluatorUtil.decode(results.get(FieldName.create("x")));`